# Getting root permissions on a file inside of nano?

Tags: permissions, nano, 14.04

I have completely the same problem as the guy in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1005/1090562). So basically I am using `nano somefile.txt` editing it and then `permissions denied` because I forgot to use sudo. The only difference from the question is that I am using `nano` and therefore accepted solution does not work.

Is there anything similar for nano?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to save the current content to a different file (best within your home directory, say `~/mytemporary-savefile`), then exit nano.

After that you copy the saved file over the original file with `sudo cp ~/mytemporary-savefile /etc/somefile.txt`