# '[Error writing /filename: Permission denied]' while trying to save a file using the nano editor

Tags: permissions, nano

Using the Nano text editor, I'm trying to save and exit a file.
 I already have the file named.

I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit. And then I click <kbd>Y</kbd> because I want to save the file. It asks for file to write, I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> to use the default name because its already named.

The problem is I get this message.

```
[Error writing /filename: Permission denied]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the permissions of the file to make sure that you have write permissions.  `ls -l *filename*` will show the permissions for that file.

Comment: Yes, it's been asked before, but the link you want is http://askubuntu.com/questions/458827/getting-root-permissions-on-a-file-inside-of-nano

Comment: Now the duplicate is: https://askubuntu.com/q/15447/215820

Answer (score 33):

Well, you don't have the rights to write that file. Use

```
sudo nano [filename]
```

Comment: So there's no way to issue a sudo save while editing the document? i.e. like vi's `:wq!` ? So if you've spent a while editing a document without realising it's protected, there's no way to save it? Bit of an oversight.

Comment: You can save to a different filename - hit Ctrl-X, Y, then change to a different filename to write to. That way you can sudo mv it after you edit

Comment: This also works if you open a file in Nano and see the message 'file is unwritable'

Comment: @dGRAMOP cool workaroud.

Answer (score 4):

If you're the admin, open another terminal

```
sudo chmod 777 <filename>
<password>
```

go back to your "nano" terminal save the file. Change permissions back on the filename if you care, they wee most likely 755

Comment: To check the original file permissions: https://askubuntu.com/a/528433

Answer (score 1):

I got your problem and to resolve this error there is an easy way. Basically, you need to do nothing but switch from normal user to root user and for that type the command:

```
sudo su
```

and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. `su` means "switch user".

Now you have full access, so do whatever you want to do because now you have super user's power.

To create a file in the `nano` text editor simply type:

```
nano [file name]
```

then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now you can use all features of `nano` without any interruption.

Comment: The answer "use sudo" was given several times... what is your addition to that?

Comment: I just started learning kali linux and i got the same problem when i was using nano text terminal so i got only one shot to tackle this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Solved it in the following way:

1. Go to Search, and type bash.
2. Right-click on bash and run as administrator.

Now it should work normally.

Answer (score 0):

If using Git Bash on Windows, it helps to run the application as an Administrator.

Comment: How does Windows come into the equation here??

Answer (score 0):

Most of what has been said works. However, there is an extreme situation. It goes like this:

`sudo nano filename`

> "Username is not in the sudoers file."

What happens if the user doesn't have this privilege? In that case, you can try the following: Open Linux in "Recovery Mode". Then select "root drop to root shell prompt". After entering the root password, type "`adduser username sudo`"."