# How do you view file permissions?

Tags: command-line, files

I want to know how to see the permissions a particular file has. Which command should I type in the terminal? However, I don't want to change it.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please mark this as Protected. This is an important question.

Answer (score 226):

If you want to see the the permission of a file you can use `ls -l /path/to/file` command.

For example

```
   ls -l acroread 
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 10490 floppy 17242 May  8  2013 acroread
```

**What does this mean ?**

First `-` represents a regular file. It gives you a hint of the type of object it is.
It can have following values.

- d (directory)
- c (character device)
- l (symlink)
- p (named pipe)
- s (socket)
- b (block device)
- D (door)
- -  (regular file)

`r` represents read permission.
  `w` represents write permission and 
  `x` represents executable permission.

First combination of `rwx` represents permission for the **owner** .
Second combination of `rwx` represents permission for the **group** .
Third combination of `rwx` represents permission for the **other** of the file.

**Octal notation**

Permission of file can also be represented in octal notation.
In octal notation

Read or `r` is represented by 4,
Write or `w` is represented by 2 
Execute `x` is represented by 1.

Sum of these three is use to represent the permission.

[`stat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/stat.1.htm) command can be used to view file permission in octal notation

```
  stat -c "%a %n" /path/of/file
```

For example

```
   stat -c "%a %n" acroread 
   755 acroread
```

Here you can see

For **owner** it is 4+2+1=7 (111 in binary)
For **group** it is 4+0+1=5 (101 in binary) and
For **other** it is 4+0+1=5 (101 in binary).

Comment: `ls -l /path/to/file | cut -c1-10` for just the permission fields.

Comment: What is input, and what is output here? What is the meaning of all the unmentioned things in the output? Speaking especially of the `1` and the `10490` and the `floppy` and the `17242`. I can make sense of the `May  8  2013`, it is the creation date, formatted, I assume. Also, what is the meaning of the `-c` and the `%a` and the `%n` in the stat command?

Comment: @NilsLindemann question is  not about the interpretation of `ls` output but  about file permission and I think all the answers here explain it very well.

Comment: @g_p Nonsense. You started it, now finish it.

Answer (score 36):

You can use either long listing:

```
ls -l [filename]
```

Or stat:

```
stat [filename]
```

Stat is more comprehensive; it shows you the access, modify and change times, as well as Inode and size information, which may or may not be useful to you.

Comment: Note: "it depends", that command will show standard permissions, however, your access can be limited by other means, acl, apparmor, and selinux can all limit access outside of what is shown by ls -l .

Answer (score 17):

Regardless of your actually using ACL permissions, if you have the `acl` package installed, you can use `getfacl <path>` to get a pretty decent breakdown of permissions on that file.

```
$ getfacl /root/
# file: root/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
other::---
```

If you *do* use ACL permissions, it'll tell you about permissions that `ls` and `stat` just can't.

```
$ sudo setfacl -m u:oli:r /root
$ getfacl /root/
# file: root/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:oli:r--
group::---
mask::r--
other::---
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also see file permission by right-clicking the file and selecting properties and there you will find permissions.