# How to execute a file via grep

Tags: command-line

I'm a basic user hoping to advance to an intermediate level.
Ok, I've a file XAMPP(manager-linux-x64.run) which when i do a

```
sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run
```

It works.
So, I was trying to go pro by doing this from its directory

```
ls | grep manager-linux-x64.run | sudo xargs ./
```

it doesnt work.it throws this error

```
xargs: ./: Permission denied
```

The file output of manager-linux-x64.run is

```
manager-linux-x64.run: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped
```

What I am essentially trying to do is 
get a list of files in the directory , 
grep the executable,
pipe the output 
and execute it using `./manager-linux-x64.run` since (sh,bash doesn't work on the .run file).

Moreover, is there any other command that can run a .run itself?

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28358088/3816360) useful.

Comment: If it works by issuing `sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run`, I don't really get what you are trying to do. For what purpose were you "trying to go pro by doing this from its directory"? What do you really mean to accomplish?

Comment: xargs pass its input as arguments to another command, you are lacking that other command.

Comment: actually, you are telling `xargs` to (try to) execute command `./` with the results of your `ls . . . | grep` as *arguments*

Comment: I still don't get why you're trying to do this.

Comment: muru, I'm only trying to  learn how to find and execute a file which is not necessarily a .sh file. Thanks

Comment: @Emma why use xargs at all?  I agree I don't see the point of your method.  Why not execute it directly?

Comment: @Sam Gleske, i get it that i can execute directly, if i have say 50 or 100 types of file like this .run file(just saying) ..would you suggest i execute it all manually?

Comment: @Emma yes, even if you had 50-100 file of the same type I would say execute them directly.  If by directly you mean referencing the script.  In general, I've not encountered a use case like you mention.  There are other cases where I'm using different file types and am using a `for` loop or `find` command to iterate across them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is a subshell. Try this:

`realpath $(ls) | grep .run$ | xargs sh -c`

Or:

`ls -d ./* | grep .run$ | xargs sh -c`

Those will work, but it might be better to use **find** if what you are trying to do is execute a file whenever it fulfills certain conditions.

`find $PWD -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.run" -exec {} \;`

---

#### Notes:

The file's executable permission [must be set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528411/how-do-you-view-file-permissions). Change with [chmod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/chmod.1.html) if needed.

**A warning**: the previous one-liners will try to execute anything they match. Read about [dot slash](http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html):

> "...A user could eliminate the need to precede commands by a dot slash (...) However, this is generally not advisable on safety and security grounds..."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54295/discussion-on-answer-by-samuel-santana-how-to-execute-a-file-via-grep).