# Directory is not a directory, can't install psa

Tags: command-line, tomcat

I'm trying to configure Tomcat on my server. I have short instruction:

```
# /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/tomcatmng --install-psa
# /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/tomcatmng --is-configured
yes
```

it's all, but I can't do that.

When I'm in `sbin`, command `cd tomcatmng` returns

```
tomcatmng: Not a directory
```

But when I write in cmd `ls` I see this. What is wrong ?
I'm trying also paste this in `sbin`:

```
tomcatmng --install-psa
```

but also error, now `command not found`.

What is wrong ?

`ls - l` in `sbin`

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root      70232 Mar 17  2017 tomcatmng
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit] and add the output of `ls -l /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin` as well as the link to the instructions you’re following and your Ubuntu version.

Comment: A command cannot be a directory. If you're asking why `tomcatmng --install-psa` doesn't work when you're in the `/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin` directory, that's because the directory is not in your `PATH`

Comment: ok, I edited this

Comment: You need full path and double check the name. And because the first examples are with root symbol #, make sure that switching to root and back you are in the same location, since it can change.

Comment: And, right, as steeldriver wrote, you cannot execute directories. It should do be: cd <your destination>. Then install tomcat: only installing commands, nobusiness with dirs.  Look here to get help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @companyn Has any of the answers helped you? Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/217657) it (✓) or clarify your needs using [edit]ing or comments.

Answer (score 1):

`tomcatmng` does not seem to be a directory at all. It could not be called with parameters as the instructions suggest and the `ls -l` will be different for a directory. So I assume it’s more likely a command to be executed.

The `#` as the first character on command lines in the instructions indicates the commands shall be executed by [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser) (opposed to `$`).

The same is also indicated by your `ls -l` output. The `x` in the [permission column](https://askubuntu.com/a/528433/250300) is present for the owner and group which are `root` and `root` according to the following columns. No other user is allowed to run this command.

In Ubuntu, the easiest way to run a command as root is to prepend `sudo`, i.e.

```
sudo /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/tomcatmng --install-psa
```

---

> I'm trying also paste this in sbin:
>
> ```
> tomcatmng --install-psa
> ```

Commands in the current directory must be moreover [prefixed with `./`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4430/54675), this is a security measure.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $PATH
```

on your PC, and you will probably find `/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/` is not in there.  If the program needs to just be executed, then:

```
chmod 700 tomcatmng
```

and type:

```
./tomcatmng
```

Comment: after ./tomcatmng I got a some commands, now I should use ./tomcatmng --install-psa ?

Comment: @companyn Exactly! You can also use the absolute path, e.g. `/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/tomcatmng --install-psa`, your current directory doesn’t matter then.