# Error writing /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php: Permission denied

Tags: server, permissions, php, phpmyadmin, sql

I tried to fix the    :`count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']`   error in  :`usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php`      but I cannot write to it.
Error :

> `Error writing /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php: Permission denied`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am trying to save a file using the nano file editor in Ubuntu \[  /:  \]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493677/i-am-trying-to-save-a-file-using-the-nano-file-editor-in-ubuntu-error-writing)

Answer (score 0):

Subdirectories of /usr/share are usually write-protected, only root is allowed to write. So you have to use `sudo` to make any changes there.